# How to count number of Items in a column by year in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Is this possible? I have the following table

```
ID   CAR  MODEL  YEAR   FUELTYPE
1    Volvo S80   2007        GAS
2    Volvo S80D  2007        DIESEL
3    Volvo S80E  2009        LPN
```

What I want to do is to count the different FUELTYPE's by year, the output would be something like this, this is the format for the Google Chart I want to use.

```
Year GAS DIESEL LPN
2007  1     1    0
2009  0     0    1
```

How can I do it with MySQL? Can I do something like this?

```
SELECT YEAR, COUNT(FUELTYPE) AS GAS, COUNT (FUELTYPE) AS DIESEL, COUNT (FUELTYPE) AS LPN
FROM  CARDATA
GROUP BY FUELTYPE
ORDER BY YEAR
```

I know it is not right as I get the same count value in each FUELTYPE - is it better to just pull it out of mysql and then use php to sort/count?

Comment: What if you do "GROUP BY YEAR, FUELTYPE"?

Comment: @Anyone That will get the count as rows, they want the count as columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only three `FuelType`, the easiest solution on this in `MySQL` is by using `GROUP BY`, and `SUM()`.

```
SELECT  Year,
        SUM(FUELTYPE = 'GAS') GAS,
        SUM(FUELTYPE = 'DIESEL') DIESEL,
        SUM(FUELTYPE = 'LPN') LPN
FROM    CARDATA
GROUP   BY YEAR
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1e0c/3)

but if you have unknown number of `FUELTYPE`, a dynamic sql is more prefereed.

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('SUM(FUELTYPE = ''',
               FUELTYPE, ''') AS ',
               CONCAT('`', FUELTYPE, '`')
               )) INTO @sql
FROM CARDATA;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT   Year, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM CARDATA
                   GROUP BY YEAR');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1e0c/2)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦═════╦════════╦═════╗
║ YEAR ║ GAS ║ DIESEL ║ LPN ║
╠══════╬═════╬════════╬═════╣
║ 2007 ║   1 ║      1 ║   0 ║
║ 2009 ║   0 ║      0 ║   1 ║
╚══════╩═════╩════════╩═════╝
```

Comment: Thanks the top part worked, as the database contains fixed number of FUELTYPE's

Comment: You're welcome. But remember that `SUM(FUELTYPE = 'LPN')` is only supported in mysql. hehe to be more database server friendly see bluefeet's answer. It uses `CASE`. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to *pivot* the row data into columns:

```
select year,
  sum(case when fueltype = 'gas' then 1 else 0 end) gas,
  sum(case when fueltype = 'diesel' then 1 else 0 end) diesel,
  sum(case when fueltype = 'lpn' then 1 else 0 end) lpn
from yt
group by year
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99c4d/1).

If you have an unknown number of `FuelType` values, then you can use a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN fueltype = ''',
      fueltype,
      ''' THEN 1 else 0 END) AS `',
      fueltype, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM yt;

SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT year, ', @sql, ' 
            from yt
            group by year');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99c4d/4).  Both this the result:

```
| YEAR | GAS | DIESEL | LPN |
-----------------------------
| 2007 |   1 |      1 |   0 |
| 2009 |   0 |      0 |   1 |
```